# How to overlap navigator.notification.prompt on top of camera in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

My app has a barcode scanner.. I am using [this plugin](https://github.com/manateeworks/phonegap-mwbarcodescanner) to be exact.

I need a prompt pop up to appear on top of the scanner when a barcode is scanned. similar to the [downloadable version of manatee](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manateeworks.barcodescanners) in googleplay.
I'm going to ask the user to enter a quantity.

I already commented out

> finish();

in scannerActivity.java 's handleDecode function so the scanner doesn't close when it has scanned something then I tried

```
navigator.notification.alert(result.code, function(){}, result.type, 'Close');
```

and

```
alert('normal alert');
```

and

```
navigator.notification.prompt(
            'notification prompt',  // message
            onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
            'Registration',            // title
            ['Ok','Exit'],             // buttonLabels
            'Jane Doe'                 // defaultText
            );
```

and

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
            ' notifcation confirm', // message
             onConfirm,            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
            'Game Over',           // title
            ['Restart','Exit']     // buttonLabels
        );
```

They all work but they don't pop up on top of the scanner. I only see them when i exit the scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the creator of the Barcode Scanner we used which is Manatee.
They said there is no way of doing this with javascript and you'd have to code this Natively.

Their Demo had a pop up because it was coded natively.